# Trouble making jQuery plugin 'jquery.shuffle.js' perform a sort

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm trying to use a jQuery plugin called shuffle.js which is supposed to work similar to Isotope - it can shuffle around divs on a page. It creates a pretty neat effect. 
(See http://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/)

I can't get it to sort. I've studied the docs and can find what I'm doing wrong. 
Test page is here:
http://res.providencejournal.com/politics/assets/pages/general-assembly/shuffle.htm

The sort is supposed to happen when you make a change to the drop down menu above the first row.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <head>

<!-- css -->
<style>
    body {
    font-family:arial;
    }

    #container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}

    /* grid */
    #grid {clear: both; position: relative}
    .item {width: 75px; height: 155px; background: #EEEEEE;font-size: 10px;margin-bottom:10px; text-align: center;}

    .item img {
    width:75px;
    }

    .last_name {
    display:none;

    }

</style>

<!-- javascript -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="jquery.shuffle.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        /* initialize shuffle plugin */
        var $grid = $('#grid');

        $grid.shuffle({
            itemSelector: '.item', // the selector for the items in the grid
            gutterWidth: 10
        });


        // Sorting options
        $('.sort-options').on('change', function() {
         var sort = this.value,
             opts = {};

         // We're given the item wrapped in jQuery
         if ( sort === 'data-party' ) {
            opts = {
             reverse: true,
             by: function($el) {
                return $el.data('data-party');
             }
            };
         } else if ( sort === 'data-district' ) {
            opts = {
             by: function($el) {
                return $el.data('data-district');
             }
            };
         } else if ( sort === 'data-last_name' ) {
            opts = {
             by: function($el) {
                return $el.data('data-last_name');
             }
            };
         }

         // Filter items
         $grid.shuffle('sort', opts);
        });


    });
</script>

 </head>

 <body>

<!-- #container -->
<div id="container">

    <select class="sort-options">
     <option value="">Default</option>
     <option value="data-district">District</option>
     <option value="data-last_name">Last name</option>
     <option value="data-party">Party</option>
    </select>

   <!-- just show two items. Actual test page has about 60 -->

        <div id="grid">
            <div data-groups='["photography"]' class="item dem" data-party="dem" data-last_name="Abney" data-district="73">
               <img src="http://res.providencejournal.com/politics/assets/images/house-senate-thumbs/rep_marvin_l_abney.jpg"><br>
               <div class="name">Rep. Marvin L. Abney</div>
               <div class="last_name">Abney</div>
               <span class="party">(D-</span><span class="district">73)</span>
            </div>
            <div data-groups='["photography"]' class="item dem" data-party="dem" data-last_name="Ackerman" data-district="45">
               <img src="http://res.providencejournal.com/politics/assets/images/house-senate-thumbs/rep_mia_a_ackerman.jpg"><br>
               <div class="name">Rep. Mia A. Ackerman</div>
               <div class="last_name">Ackerman</div>
               <span class="party">(D-</span><span class="district">45)</span>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
<!-- /#container -->

</body>

</html>
```

Firebug indicates that the event is firing but the divs don't move. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if relevant anymore but inside the sorting function you don't need to add the 'data-' prefix, although it is required on the div element.